# Prove or disprove $( A ∩ B ) ∪ C = A ∩ ( B ∪ C )$ if and only if $C ⊆ A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

This question was in my exam, I didn't know how to continue and got stuck after I opened the braces:

$(A ∩ B) ∪ C = (C ∪ A) ∩ (C ∪ B)$

$A ∩ ( B ∪ C ) = (A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ C)$

I didn't know how to prove $C ⊆ A$ from there.
But I managed to prove the opposite direction...

Comment: Double inclusion ?

Comment: Left to right: $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$: either $x \in C$, and it is Ok, or $x \in A \cap B$ and it's Ok. Now, right to left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $C \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq A$, so $C \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

$$AB+C=AB+AC\iff C=AC$$ which is true if

either $A=U$ or  each member of $C$ lies $\in A$